# How to type a text very fast?

Tags: sikuli

Im trying to type a text detected by OCR very fast. At the moment the typing is kinda fast but I would like to type it instantly if possible. I heard of Settings.TypeDelay but it does the opposite of what Im looking for cause I would like to reduce the time it takes to type, not increase it :(

I also found a post of Raiman talking about a write() command that could potentialy fix my issue but I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
paste(text)
```

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: Solved :) Thanks a lot !